# When did the .NET CLI (i.e., dotnet command) start shipping with the .NET SDK and with Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I was sitting here wondering when Microsoft created and shipped the dotnet CLI to create a better line experience and wrap MSBuild.

What .NET SDK version did the CLI release with?
Also, what version of Visual Studio did it coincide with?

If there is a network that would be better to ask this type of question, let me know.

Comment: You're specifically asking about the `dotnet` that ships in Visual Studio? You can download `dotnet` separately, with or without the SDK.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I want to know when the dotnet cli was shipped (in general) and what Visual Studio version it was first shipped with.